# Let $a, b ∈ Z$ with $gcd(a, b) = 1$, and let $c ∈ Z$. Show the equivalence: $ab | c ⇔ a | c$ and $b | c$.

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

I'm not sure how to do this question. Please help.

All I know that $gcd(a,b)=1$

But what can I do with this extra information?

"Hint: To prove the implication “$⇐$”, start from $a | c$ and use the fact, due to $gcd(a, b) = 1$, that for any $k ∈ Z$, if $b | ka$ then $b | k$."

---

b)  Find integers $a, b, c ∈ Z$ with $gcd(a, b)$ does not equal to 1 where the equivalence in ($a$) does not hold.

^ I am so lost from what the question asking

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

[Integers $x, \, y$ exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) with $xa+yb=1$, so $k=xka+ybk$ is a multiple of $b$.

Comment: so how can I find the implification for both sides?

Comment: @JasonThai Use $k=c/a$.

Comment: how does k=c/a involves with implification? like what is my first step from this problem? Like I am so confused :(

Comment: @JasonThai Since $b|c=ka$, $b|k$ so $ab|ka=c$.

Comment: how do you know that b|c = ka? wouldn't c =ka?

Comment: @JasonThsi That's what I'm saying. If $b|c$ then, since $c=ka$, $b|ka$. From the hint, also $b|k$. So $ab|ka$ or, in other words, $ab|c$.

Comment: So that proven that b|c is <=> ab|c. how about a|c?

Comment: @JasonThai My argument also used $a|c$, so it proved $a|c\land b|c\implies ab|c$; the other direction is trivial since $a|ab\land b|ab$.

Comment: Ok. I want to clarify abit. ka=c=k. k=xka+ybk=xca+ybc=c. So, ab|ka <=> b|ka. ab|(c|a)a <=> b|(c|a)a which cancels the a leaving ab|c <=> b|c. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @JasonThai $c$ is only equal to $ka$, not to $k$ (unless $c=k=0$ or $a=1$). But we've shown that $b|ka\implies b|k$.

Comment: what I did was ax+by=gcd(a,b)=1. multiple by c which get acx+byc=c. Using the proposition (if a|b and a|c, the Vx,yeZ, a|(bx+cy); in particular, a|(b+c) and a|(b-c)). So that means that b|(acx+byc) is equal to b|c. Im not sure if I am correct